# XPathNavigator.Evaluate returning incorrect value?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I'm expecting this code to return true but it doesn't ? What am I missing here.

```
 string xml = @"<!DOCTYPE root [ <!ELEMENT e (e*) ><!ATTLIST e  id    ID    #REQUIRED>]>
         <data><e id=""NUM_CPUS"">2</e><e id=""ACE_PRESENT"">1</e></data>";
  XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(new StringReader(xml));
  string expr = "(id('NUM_CPUS'))>=1 and (id('ACE_PRESENT'))=1";
  XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();

  XPathExpression query = nav.Compile(expr);

  object result = nav.Evaluate(query);
  bool b = bool.Parse(result.ToString());

  if (!b)
    throw new Exception("Should be true");
```

Comment: Answered my own question, you must have the DTD at the top: <!DOCTYPE root [ <!ELEMENT e (e*) >
                 <!ATTLIST e  id    ID    #REQUIRED>
]>

Comment: If you know the XPath expression evaluates to a boolean value then you can simply do `bool result = (bool)nav.Evaluate(query);`, there is no need to convert to a string to then parse that as a boolean. As for your sample, it returns false I think, even as edited as it has `<e id=""ACE_PRESENT"">0</e>` but checks `(id('ACE_PRESENT'))=1`. But if hadn't had any DTD before declaring attributes of type ID then yes, with XPath 1.0 a DTD needs to define ID attributes to be able to use the `id` function successfully.

Comment: The returned `false` is correct, because the string value of `<e id=""ACE_PRESENT"">0</e>` is 0, but the expression checks if it is equal to 1. 0 = 1 is `false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the header, makes this work:

```
<!DOCTYPE root [ <!ELEMENT e (e*) ><!ATTLIST e  id    ID    #REQUIRED>]>
```

Comment: Without the header, you will always get false